# i got error (Error get data from ajax)

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

hi i am unable to call my ajax function in codeigniter , below is my script :
whenever i click edit button from my data table i got error (Error get data from ajax) , could u pls help me where i am doing wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var save_method;

   function edit_question(id)
    {

      save_method = 'update';
      $('#form')[0].reset(); // reset form on modals
      // document.write("test");
      //Ajax Load data from ajax
      $.ajax({
        // document.write("test");
        url : "<?php echo base_url('index.php/test_cont/ajax_edit/')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {   
            $('[name="question_id"]').val(data.question_id);
          //  $('[name="cid"]').val("<?php  //echo $a; ?>");
            $('[name="cid"]').val(data.cid);
            $('[name="ques"]').val(data.question);
          //  $('[name="opa"]').val(data.options);
           // $('[name="opb"]').val(data.options);
           // $('[name="opc"]').val(data.options);
           // $('[name="opd"]').val(data.options);
            $('[name="ra"]').val(data.answer);
            $('[name="marks"]').val(data.marks);
            $('#modal_form').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Questions'); // Set title to Bootstrap modal title

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
    });
    }
```

i have a controller name test_cont , here's code :

```
     public function ajax_edit($id)
      {
      $data = $this->m->get_by_id($id);
      echo json_encode($data);
      }

     public function question_update()
    {
    $data = array(
        'course_id'=>$this->input->post('cid'),   
        'question'=>$this->input->post('ques'),
        'marks'=>$this->input->post('marks'),
        'options' => $options,
        'answer' => $this->input->post('ra'),
      );
    $this->m->question_update(array('question_id' => $this->input->post('question_id')), $data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
   }
```

Comment: please ```console.log(data)``` in ```success``` and check the console.

Comment: i got this log on console :   Uncaught ReferenceError: edit_question is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM295 test_cont:127)

Comment: this is edit button code :  -----------   <a href="#" onclick="edit_question(<?php echo $que->question_id;?>)" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>

Comment: Your javascript function is not reachable to that anchor tag.

Comment: Please try with jQuery completely, you are using half core-javascript, and jquery for ajax.